# Open popup window with accesskeys

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For a long time I was using this script to open popups via accesskeys.

But with the latest version of Chrome on Mac, it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

It works in FF and Safari.

```html
<a accesskey="w" href="javascript:window.open()">
    Press ALT+W to open new window
</a>
```

Comment: `Alt+W` works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/b9Lfgm9k/

Comment: You could check the console if it is saying something like: *Blocked opening '' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.*

Comment: just forgot to say that this happened on mac, dont know if windows has similar issue

Comment: there is a warning popup blocked, but if I set to always allow open popups for current domain even though no windows are opened and console.log is empty